# Linkedin ads set link to uploaded image

Tags: facebook, linkedin-api, ads

If I paste an url in the linkedin ad itself it uses the meta property og:image as an image and as a link.

But if I upload a custom image I have not been able to achive this since it does not add a link to the image.

Is it possible to use this image as a link aswell?

Answer (score 1):

This changed last week. Now when you upload a custom image, there is a field for "Destination URL".

It used to be that when you uploaded a custom image, it would appear as though clicking the image just popped the image up in a lightbox, but when the ad actually gets served, the image would function as a click to the landing page.

All that was super confusing, and they finally fixed it.